# Dropbox v2 api for iOS - how do you get clientMTime?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I'm migrating an app built with the Dropbox v1 API to the v2 API. The app needs to sync files in source dropbox folder to app documents folder. The current version of the app uses the clientMTime to skip syncing files which have not changed. With v1, I got the required info--specifically the path and clientMTime of each file in the Dropbox folder--by doing this...

```
//  ==============================================================
//  getDBMetadata
//  ==============================================================

- (void)getDBMetadata 
{
    NSString* theOPMLFilesRoot = @"/";
    [self.restClient loadMetadata:theOPMLFilesRoot withHash:self.opmlFilesHash];
}


//  ==============================================================
//  restClient:loadedMetadata:
//  ==============================================================

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata 
{
    self.opmlFilesHash = metadata.hash;               // Used to check for changes

    for (DBMetadata* __unused theMetadata in metadata.contents) {
        LogDebug(@"Path: %@, clientMtime: %@.", theMetadata.path , [theMetadata.clientMtime toStr]);
    }

    [self synchronizeFilesUsingDBMetadata:metadata];
}
```

The v2 iOS API docs for Dropbox object 'DBFILESMetadata' include 'path' but **do not** list clientMtime as an included property (which they're calling 'field'). Is there a way to get clientMTime with v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DBFILESMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESMetadata.html) can represent a file, folder, or deleted item. Only files have a client modified time though, so [`clientModified`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESFileMetadata.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESFileMetadata(py)clientModified) is only available on [`DBFILESFileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESFileMetadata.html), which represents a file only.

[`DBFILESFileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESFileMetadata.html) is a subclass of [`DBFILESMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESMetadata.html). To check if a particular [`DBFILESMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESMetadata.html) is a [`DBFILESFileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESFileMetadata.html), you can use `isKindOfClass` as shown [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#response-handling-edge-cases). You can then cast it to the relevant subclass.

Also, note that [`rev`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESFileMetadata.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESFileMetadata(py)rev) or [`contentHash`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESFileMetadata.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESFileMetadata(py)contentHash) are better options for checking if the file has changed.